# Calculate and store average for following table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, moving-average, rolling-average

I am trying to calculate average of `P` value in following table as per month in `per_date` column grouped by `qu_def` column.

[image]

and store it as follows in a SQL Server table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a query like this:

```
select qu_def, for_cur,
       datefromparts(year(per_date), month(per_date), 1) as per_date,
       max(per_date) as date, avg(p) as p
from t
group by qu_def, for_cur,
       datefromparts(year(per_date), month(per_date), 1);
```

You can use `INSERT` to put this in an existing table or `INTO` to create a new table.